# Persist parent of a not entity Class by JPA which is Entity

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, persistence

In java I have 4 classes (**Cat, Mammal, Animal, Zoo**).

The relation between them is:

```
{Cat extends Mammal, (concreat class)-
Mammal extends Animal (Mammal is abstract)-
And Animal is not abstract-
Zoo has a List of Mammals(List<Mammal>)}
```

Now i want to persist `Zoo`.

Only `Zoo` and `Animal` are defined as an Entity and others related table for them in DB. (Mammal is not an entity)

Whould you plz tell that can i do this and how?

I prefer not to chang the design of my classes if it is possible

Comment: JPA persists entities. Not arbitrary classes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly as I require some of the code to determine the solution but it sounds like you might benefit from this

[article explaining single-table inheritance in JPA](http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/05/14/jpa-single-table-inheritance-example/)

If you'd like you can please post the syntax of your classes so we can assess further.

Kind Regards,